# Как выбрать все элементы в DOM и сделать их кликабельными

Tags: javascript, dom

Доброго времени суток. Нужна помощь
Есть таблица, хочу каждый элемент сделать кликабельным
Вот так работает :

```
var variable = document.getElementById('test');
```

Но кликабельным получается только первый элемент естественно

```
variable.addEventListener("click", showNumber);
```

Пытаюсь так чтобы все:

```
var variable = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var variable = document.querySelectorAll('.class');

variable.addEventListener("click", showNumber);
```

Не получается.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) и [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) возвращают коллекции, следовательно, чтобы назначить обработчик, нужно пройтись по всей коллекции и назначить его каждому элементу, например:

```
var variables = document.querySelectorAll('.class');
[].forEach.call(variables, function(variable){
    variable.addEventListener("click", showNumber);
});
```

Comment: Зачем тратится на создание пустого массива и поиска в его прототипе метода? `Array.prototype` проще.

Comment: @Other, писать дольше, а так же тесты показывают что особой разницы нет. Есть какие-то основания говорить, что лучше `Array.prototype` кроме _проще_? тем более, не совсем понятно, что под этим словом имеется ввиду в данном случае

Comment: Некоторые с пеной у рта доказывали что брать сразу у прототипа дешевле, чем создавать и искать. Лень проверять, поэтому я просто предложил.

Comment: @Other, стоит отметить что литералы это не совсем обычные объекты

Comment: Да, но при интерпретации их всё-равно пропускают через мясорубку конструктора.

Comment: @Other, без разбора исходников движка - нельзя это гарантировать

Comment: Будь по Вашему, я просто предложил.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523742/191482) @Grundy, несколько вариантов навесить событие:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".element");

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        elements[i].classList.toggle("active");
    });
}
```

```css
.element.active {
    background: #7fcdff;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">element 1</div>
<div class="element">element 2</div>
<div class="not-element">not element</div>
<div class="element">element 3</div>
```

---

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".element");

for (const element of elements) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        element.classList.toggle("active");
    })
}
```

```css
.element.active {
    background: #7fcdff;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">element 1</div>
<div class="element">element 2</div>
<div class="not-element">not element</div>
<div class="element">element 3</div>
```

---

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.element')].forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
       element.classList.toggle("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.element.active {
    background: #7fcdff;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">element 1</div>
<div class="element">element 2</div>
<div class="not-element">not element</div>
<div class="element">element 3</div>
```

---

`.forEach` и стрелочные функции

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".element");

elements.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("click", () => { 
            element.classList.toggle("active");
        });
    }
);
```

```css
.element.active {
    background: #7fcdff;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">element 1</div>
<div class="element">element 2</div>
<div class="not-element">not element</div>
<div class="element">element 3</div>
```

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('.element')]` -- у `NodeList` и так есть метод `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

Cобытия клика «пузырьками» поднимаются наверх: от `<td>` к `<tr>` и `<table>`. Может, просто ловить события клика у `<table>` – и определять оригинального инициатора клика?

```js
var table = document.getElementById('e-table'),
  out = document.getElementById('out');

table.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if( e.target.tagName !== 'TD') return; // ждём клика по <td>
  out.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
});
```

```css
body{font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;}
td{border:1px solid #CCC; cursor:pointer; width:15px;height:15px; text-align:center}
#out{padding:5px;width:60px;height:40px;background-color:#CCC;text-align:center}
```

```html
<table id="e-table">
  <tr> <td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>.</td> <td>..</td> <td>...</td> </tr>
</table>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: @Anton, если интересно, этот приём называется `делегирование событий`: https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation