# Изменение цвета кнопки при щелчке

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть сайт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Верстаю шапку сайта. Необходимо, чтобы при щелчке на ***одну*** кнопку цвет этой кнопки становился сиреневым, а выделенные до этого кнопки становились белового цвета

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  all__buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.header__button');
  /*selected__button.click= function(){
        selected__button.backgroundColor='#5f3ec0';
    
  };*/

  function changeColor(inputbutton) {
    inputbutton.backgroundColor = '#5f3ec0';
  }

  [].forEach.call(all__buttons, function(selected__button) {
    selected__button.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.globalcontainer {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.header>.header__text {
  position: relative;
  width: 93px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 129px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: TT Norms;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 100%;
  /* identical to box height, or 24px */
  color: #000000;
}


/*
.header__buttons {
    left: 0;
    top: 193px;
}
*/

.header__button {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="globalcontainer">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header__text">Обзоры</div>
    <div class="header__buttons">
      <span>
        <button class="header__button">Все</button>
        <button class="header__button">Видео</button>
        <button class="header__button">Текст</button>
        <button class="header__button">Обзоры</button>
        <button class="header__button">Сравнения</button>
        <button class="header__button">Краш видео</button>
        <button class="header__button">Распаковка</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но в результате после щелчка мыши цвет кнопки не меняется на сиреневый. Подскажите как добиться изменения цвета кнопки при щелчке. Ссылка [Как выбрать все элементы в DOM и сделать их кликабельными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523736/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-dom-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8) не помогла.

Comment: Да и не поможет, не понимаю с чего @АлексейШиманский реший, что это дубликат..

Comment: @De.Minov гляньте на первую версию вопроса и увидите

Comment: А сейчас вопрос совсем по-другому звучит. Имхо это не переоткрыавть надо, а новый задавать

Comment: У Вас цвет задаётся так: **inputbutton.backgroundColor = '#5f3ec0';** Нужно так: **inputbutton.style.backgroundColor = '#5f3ec0';**