# Не работает querySelectorAll на второй константе

Tags: javascript, html

```
const btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const content = document.querySelectorAll(".content--visible");
btn.forEach(btn => {
   btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (content.classList.contains("content--hidden")) {
         btn.textContent = "Скрыть";
      } else {
         btn.textContent = "Показать ещё";
      }

      content.classList.toggle("content--hidden");
   });
});
```

выбивает ошибку: `TypeError: content.classList is undefined`

вот рабочий вариант без `querySelectorAll`:

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const content = document.querySelector(".content--visible");
btn.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (content.classList.contains("content--hidden")) {
      btn.textContent = "Скрыть";
    } else {
      btn.textContent = "Показать ещё";
    }

    content.classList.toggle("content--hidden");
  });
})
```

```css
.content--hidden {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.wrapper>div {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" type="button">
    Показать элемент
</button>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="1 content--visible content--hidden">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, natus? Nostrum distinctio itaque ex! Pariatur eligendi error ab. Reiciendis ipsum deserunt magni vel veniam porro doloremque iure fuga voluptatem commodi!

  </div>
  <div class="2 content--visible content--hidden">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, natus? Nostrum distinctio itaque ex! Pariatur eligendi error ab. Reiciendis ipsum deserunt magni vel veniam porro doloremque iure fuga voluptatem commodi!

  </div>
</div>
```

но мне нужно чтобы работало со всеми классами

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выбрать все элементы в DOM и сделать их кликабельными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523736/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-dom-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const content = document.querySelectorAll(".content--visible");

buttons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    content.forEach((item) => toggleContent(item, btn))
  });
});

function toggleContent(item, btn) {
  if (item.classList.contains("content--hidden")) {
    btn.textContent = "Скрыть";
  } else {
    btn.textContent = "Показать ещё";
  }

  item.classList.toggle("content--hidden");
}
```

`TypeError: content.classList is undefined` потому что вы пытаетесь обратиться к массиву, а не конкретному элементу.

Для того чтобы обратиться к каждому элементу пройдитесь по нему в цикле, например через `forEach`

А если по вашей задумке в `content` должен быть 1 элемент, а не массив, тогда стоит заменить:

`document.querySelectorAll(".content--visible")`
на
`document.querySelector(".content--visible")`

Comment: по задумке элементов будет много и функционал этого скрипта будет переиспользоваться на одной странице несколько раз

Comment: @Shalindor Обновил сообщение. Добавил код, попробуйте

Comment: Спасибо огромное код заработал))

Comment: Знал бы вас лично поставил бы пиво

Comment: Не массив, а NodeList, не надо путать новичка.

Answer (score 0):

content - массив, для применения данных к каждому элементу массива надо применять цикл

Comment: можете пожалуйста написать пример  или решение я совсем новичок в js пока что не представляю как это реализовать.

Comment: Странно что в первый раз догадался итерировать.... Мне кажется жизнь была бы проще, если бы в текст ошибки добавили бы что-то типа "content is list. May be you want iterate?"

Comment: @Shalindor Это не ваш код? Вы же сами написали в первый раз `btn.forEach`, теперь тоже самое для `content`

Comment: @Shalindor Вы же знаете циклы...

Comment: Спасибо вам большое учить мне ещё и учить))